# Can't use substring in *ngFor in Angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

I loop through a list of objects using a variable called `setting` who's names are accessible in the following format:

```
setting['_name']
```

And the setting names are of the following format:

```
<name>(<parameters>)
```

and I have to display data from another object called `formValues` that uses the `name` part as the keys.
So I tried running:

```
<div *ngFor="let para of 
Object.keys(formValues[setting['_name'].substring(0,setting['_name'].indexOf('('))])">
```

But it's not working.

Can you point out what I'm doing wrong or suggest another way to make it work.

Comment: Your code in Stackblitz will be more helpful to understand your issue. Can you create one?

Comment: I went ahead and made a dummy. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8acxn).

Comment: Hey Dude!! You are the absolute best. While implementing the dummy for you, i figured out a workaround. Thanks a ton. But it would be awesome if you could come up with something that changes the html only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a workaround, but this still is not the answer i was looking for. if someone can solve it using the HTML only, It would be great.

I created a function in my Typescript to do the substring part:

```
getMultiName(settingname : string){
return settingname.substring(0, settingname.indexOf('('));
}
```

and then I used `getMultiName(setting['_name'])` instead of `setting.substring(0, setting.indexOf('('))` in the html.

You can check out the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8acxn).